# Errors in newly created GTK# project

Tags: c#, monodevelop, gtk#, ubuntu-14.10

I just installed `Monodevelop 5.7.0` in Ubuntu 14.10 in a 32bit machine. I created some console `C#` applications for testing and everything works fine. But when I tried to create a `GTK#` project and execute it, I have the following 3 errors in the Program and MainWindow classes:

- `the type or namespace name 'Init' does not exist in the namespace 'Application'`
- `the type or namespace name 'Run' does not exist in the namespace 'Application'`
- `the type or namespace name 'Quit' does not exist in the namespace 'Application'`

I've been trying to add some references and searching for other solutions but with no luck.

These are the classes of the application:

Program.cs

```
using System;
using Gtk;

namespace Application
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            Application.Init ();
            MainWindow win = new MainWindow ();
            win.Show ();
            Application.Run ();
        }
    }  
}
```

MainWindow.cs

```
using System;
using Gtk;

public partial class MainWindow: Gtk.Window
{
    public MainWindow () : base (Gtk.WindowType.Toplevel)
    {
        Build ();
    }

    protected void OnDeleteEvent (object sender, DeleteEventArgs a)
    {
        Application.Quit ();
        a.RetVal = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the relevant excerpts of the code in your question?

Comment: Is `namespace Application {}` yours or does it come from the boilerplate code MonoDevelop generates when creating your project? A lot of problems come into play when you have a class whose name is the same as a namespace's, the IDE is not supposed to do that.

Comment: it's generated by MonoDevelop...

Comment: My version of MonoDevelop (3.0.2 on Gentoo) uses the project name as a basis for the namespace around `MainClass` (`namespace monogtktest` in my, well, tests). I can't see `namespace Application` anywhere. Can you specify the version of MonoDevelop you're running?

Comment: Hah :) Gentoo doesn't even have that as an unstable package, I would have to go through an overlay. That means something. Good luck :)

Comment: Thanks, i just fix it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just fixed it. When I created the project erroneously I named it "*02*", so in the class `Program.cs`, by default **Monodevelop** named it "*Application*" instead of the project name, making the errors appear.

You must change the namespace "*Application*" in the class Program.cs:

**Program.cs**

```
using System;
using Gtk;

namespace two // for example
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            Application.Init ();
            MainWindow win = new MainWindow ();
            win.Show ();
            Application.Run ();
        }
    }  
}
```

To avoid this remember do not use just numbers in the name of your projects.